# Xcode Symbol navigator - Symbols displayed twice once each for iOS device and iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode9.3

The Xcode Symbol navigator is listing the framework supplied symbols twice; once each for iOS and Simulator.

For instance, here's **NSObject** listed for Simulator

[image]

and **NSObject** listed for iOS Device

[image]

Similarly, here's **UIDevice** listed for Simulator

[image]

and **UIDevice** listed for iOS Device

[image]

As I recall, this never used to be the case. The symbols should be listed only once.

<strike>I am using **Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145)**, running on **macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E202)**</strike>.

**Update**: I am using **Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)**, running on **macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 (17F77)** (both of them current as of this writing).

How do I get back to the default behaviour of showing each symbol only once?

I have already tried:

- Cleaning the build folder,
- Restarting Xcode,
- Deleting derive data
- Restarting the system.
- Reinstalling Xcode.

The behaviour is observed in every project that I open with Xcode.

Comment: Does this happen in other user accounts on the same computer? Can you flush Xcode preferences?

Comment: I have only one user account in my system. Let me create a new account and try.

Comment: Not happening in a newly created user account.

Comment: As I figured. Would you be willing to flush Xcode settings plist (probably in ~/Library/Preferences)? If so **copy to your desktop** incase anything goes wrong.

Comment: Done. Didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://gist.github.com/maciekish/66b6deaa7bc979d0a16c50784e16d697)? Bit of a Hail Mary here.

Comment: That worked. Can you add it as an answer with the script inline? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the issue only appears on your user account, try:

1. Flushing Xcode preferences plist file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`. (**Warning:** This will reset all the custom user preferences).
2. Run the following reset script from [here](https://gist.github.com/maciekish/66b6deaa7bc979d0a16c50784e16d697):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   killall Xcode
   xcrun -k
   xcodebuild -alltargets clean
   rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
   rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang.$(whoami)/ModuleCache"
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
   rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/*
   open /Applications/Xcode.app
   ```

Most likely some setting got switched on that you can't figure out how to switch off. If you would like to figure out what the setting exactly is you can probably compare the plists.